# How to get the difference between two points in time in milliseconds

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++-chrono

How can I get (using the `std::chrono` library) the difference between two points in time in milliseconds?

I could do that using this:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> foo = now + std::chrono::milliseconds(100);
    
std::chrono::duration<float> difference = foo - now;
    
const int milliseconds = difference.count() * 1000;
```

How can I get this time in milliseconds, so I can use the duration as an `unsigned int`, and not a `float` and then multiply by 1000?

Comment: `chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count()`

Comment: To whoever comes here after googling for a way to get a time difference in milliseconds: careful! This question, and the answers, focus on how to get a duration as an **integer** amount of milliseconds. If you have time points with a higher precision (e.g. nanoseconds) and you want to preserve all digits without truncating, but you want to convert to milliseconds, you can use `duration_cast<duration<float,std::milli>(difference).count()`. Using `duration_cast<milliseconds>(duration).count()` will truncate your digits since `milliseconds` is basically a `duration<long,milli>`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[`std::chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) has two template parameters, the second being exactly the unit of measure. You can invoke [`std::chrono::duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) to cast from one duration type to another. Also, there is a predefined duration type for milliseconds: [`std::chrono::milliseconds`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). Composing this together:

```
auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(foo - now);
```

To get the actual number of milliseconds, use [`duration::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count):

```
auto ms = milliseconds.count();
```

Its return type is `duration::rep`, which for standard duration types like `std::chrono::milliseconds` is a signed integer of unspecified size.

Answer (score 13):

```
chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count()
```

Answer (score 5):

I had issues with the duration printing out with letters like e-09.  Here's how I fixed it:

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
< run your function or code here >
auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = finish - start;
std::cout << "Elapsed Time: " << elapsed.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
```

And now I get desired results:

```
Elapsed Time: 34.406 seconds
```

Comment: I find two things strange in that code: First, the chrono library uses rational numbers (integral numerators and denominators), so using double seems odd here. Secondly, I don't see where the conversion from milliseconds to seconds is happening.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/duration_cast/

```
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>();
```