# How to find Time Duration between two dates with Hours minutes and seconds in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, mktime, time-t

I need to find the time difference between two given dates.

I have tried the following code but not able to convert it into hours mins secs

```
         const char *time_details = "06/10/2021 16:35:12";
struct tm tm;
strptime(time_details, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm); // Prev date

time_t t = mktime(&tm);

const char *time_details1 = "06/11/2021 14:35:12";
struct tm tm1;
strptime(time_details1, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm1); // future date

time_t t33 = mktime(&tm1);

int timediff1 = difftime(t33,t);

    int seconds1 = timediff1%60;
int hour1 =seconds1/ 3600;
int minutes1 = seconds1 / 60 ;
```

The above always shows '0' in hours mins seconds. But getting some value in

Comment: If you're using c++11 then take a look at using <chrono> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657511/chrono-the-difference-between-two-points-in-time-in-milliseconds

Comment: for the code above the math should be like: `int hour1 = timediff1 / 3600; int minutes1 = timediff1 % 3600 / 60;` because `int seconds1 = timediff1%60` gives seconds from 0 to 59  and you obviuosly cannot calculate hours and minutes from this value.

Comment: @dewaffled thank you it helped. I got the output. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

With C++2a early support you can do something like this

```
std::tm tm1 = {}, tm2 = {};

std::stringstream ss("06/10/2021 16:35:12 06/11/2021 14:35:12");

ss >> std::get_time(&tm1, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");
ss >> std::get_time(&tm2, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");
auto tp1 = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm1));
auto tp2 = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm2));
auto diff = tp2 - tp1;

// convert to human-readable form
auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::days>(diff);
diff -= d;
auto h = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(diff);
diff -= h;
auto m = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(diff);
diff -= m;
auto s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(diff);

std::cout << std::setw(2) << d.count() << "d:"
   << std::setw(2) << h.count() << "h:"
   << std::setw(2) << m.count() << "m:"
   << std::setw(2) << s.count() << 's';
```

And full support offers `operator<<` for `duration` class. For C++11 `std::chrono::days` and `hours` must be replaced by equivalents, e.g. `duration<int, std::ratio<86400>>` for `days`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
void computeTimeDiff(struct TIME t1, struct TIME t2, struct TIME *difference){
    
    if(t2.seconds > t1.seconds)
    {
        --t1.minutes;
        t1.seconds += 60;
    }

    difference->seconds = t1.seconds - t2.seconds;
    if(t2.minutes > t1.minutes)
    {
        --t1.hours;
        t1.minutes += 60;
    }
    difference->minutes = t1.minutes-t2.minutes;
    difference->hours = t1.hours-t2.hours;
}
```